# SQL server , Add data in multi value attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Photos with attribute comments 
i want to declare that comments take many values
and want to know how to insert a new value to it

Comment: Don't do that - it violates even the **first normal form** of database design! Each column for each row can have **one value and one value only** (or it contains NULL) - but **don't store multiple values in a single column** !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have a column photo_id in your comments table. This would let you have a lot of comments for each photo.

The way you are saying it, it would let you have the same comment in different photos, but that looks less likely to be what you really want.

Something like this:

```
photos:
id primary key

comments
id primary_key
photo_id foreign_key referencing photos(id)
```